# What is meaning of the response status word 0x61xx from a smart card?

Tags: protocols, smartcard, javacard, apdu, error-code

I wrote a Java Card applet that saves some data into the APDU buffer at offset `ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA` and sends those bytes as a response.

```
Util.arrayCopy(Input_Data, (short)0, buffer, (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, (short)Datalength);
apdu.setOutgoing();
apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)(DataLength) );

apdu.sendBytesLong(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, (short)(DataLength));
```

I tested this in a simulator without any problem. But when I test this on a real smart card (Java Card v2.2.1 manufactured by Gemalto), I get the status word `0x6180` as response.

My command APDU is `00 40 00 00 80 Data`, where data has a length of 128 bytes, so I have 4+128 bytes in the buffer and (260-(4+128)) byte is null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your simulator probably uses `T=1` transport protocol, but your real card does not. It uses `T=0` protocol, which means it can either receive data, or send data in a single APDU.

Status word `0x6180` indicates there are `0x80` bytes to receive from the card. Generally, `61XX` means `XX` bytes to receive.

How to receive them? Well, there is a special APDU command called `GET RESPONSE`. You should call it each time you get `61XX` status word. Use `XX` as the `Le` byte of your `GET RESPONSE` APDU

```
APDU -> 61 XX
00 C0 00 00 XX -> your data 90 00
```

---

A few other notes on your code:

- `Datalength` vs `DataLength`?
- Copy your output data to `0` instead of `ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA`
- Why do you cast `DataLength` to `short` each time? Is it `short`? Do not cast then. Is it `byte`? You cast it in a wrong way then, because unsigned byte value `> 0x80` will be cast to a negative `short`. The correct cast from an unsigned `byte` to a `short` is `(short) (DataLength & 0xFF)`
- Use `setOutgoingAndSend` whenever you can. It is much simpler.
- Use `arrayCopyNonAtomic` instead of `arrayCopy` whenever you are not copying to a persistent array. Performance of `arrayCopyNonAtomic` is much better.

Comment: Excuse me..I don't undrestand apdu 00 C0 00 00 xx. I send apdu 00 40 00 00 80 Data that selects my function with INS=40. How to select my function If I use C0 in apdu?

Comment: @FatemeJafari You will use `00 40 00 00 80 Data`, then you will receive `61XX`, then you will use `00 C0 00 00 XX`. It is just a special command for receiving data from the card. It will give you the response for your `40` command. You don't have to select any other applet...

Comment: Thanks very much Dear vojta. In this state I will get my response in one apdu?If I have a response more than 256 what should I do?

Comment: @FatemeJafari You will never get your response in one APDU with `T=0` protocol. You will have to call GET RESPONSE after each APDU that results in `61XX`.

Comment: @FatemeJafari For responses longer than 256 bytes there is this `ExtendedLength` interface. However, it is usually not supported by `T=0` cards. That is why I don't like it and I prefer implementing long responses by myself in multiple APDUs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122444/discussion-between-fateme-jafari-and-vojta).

Comment: Excuse me..my data length was 128 byte .I think card 2.2.1 can transfer 256 byte in each apdu. Is it correct?in this sample  why  I can't get response normal?